# How can I find all number entries in a file

Tags: python, regex

I have file with a section that looks like this:

```
report from:PCAT1.DB   created at:2019-06-27 14:32:24   generated at:2019-06-27 14:35:10

number of campaigns:466

unique assets:950   downloaded assets:920   deleted assets:0   total assets: 922
```

What I am attempting to do is identify the numbers alongside certain headings. I.E. I want the unique assets and the total assets and then put them into a dictionary or list.

below is some code I have been using but it is picking up all numbers that have at least 3 digits so I am also getting the time/date values as well which I don't want.

```
assets = []

with open("C://AdSmart Results//Rack_54//cdb_report2.html") as adsmart:
    for line in adsmart.readlines():
        if re.search(r'assets:\d{3}', line):
            assets.append(line)

print(assets)
```

The assets dictionary should end up populated with the type of asset and the corresponding values:

```
assets = { "Unique Assets": "950", "Total Assets": "922"}
```

As ever, all help and guidance is greatly appreciated. Apologies if this is a duplicate of a question that I have managed to miss in my searches.

Comment: How are you getting time and date numbers? They don't have `assets:` before them.

Comment: Another issue you will encounter is that you add the entire line once you find a match to your regex (```assets.append(line)```). So the moment it finds [..]assets:950[..] you will add the entire line to your assets dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a variant of the code that works as I think you wanted:

```
import re

assets = {}

with open("C://AdSmart Results//Rack_54//cdb_report2.html") as adsmart:
    for line in adsmart.readlines():
        for match in re.finditer(r'(\w+ assets):\s*(\d+)', line):
            assets[match.group(1)] = int(match.group(2))

print(assets)
```

What changed:

1. You have more than one figure per line, so you need to iterate over the matches in each line. So I changed the `if re.search(...)` to `for match in re.finditer(...)`. Whereas [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.search) returns a `Match` object for the first match found (if any), [re.finditer](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.finditer) returns *every* match object. Then we can loop over that.
2. The regular expression `(\w+ assets)` matches a word, then a space, then the word "assets"
3. I didn't understand whether you only want 3-digit numbers, but that's what `\d{3}` is. It's the same as `\d\d\d`. I changed it to `\d+`, meaning "one or more digits".
4. The parentheses in the regular expression are capturing groups. So for each `Match` object, `match.group(1)` is the text that matched the regex inside the first pair of parentheses, `match.group(2)` is the second, etc.
5. I changed `assets` from a list to a dict, since that's what you show in your desired output. Then we can map the asset type (`match.group(1)`) to the count (`int(match.group(2))`).

This is the output I get:

```
{'unique assets': 950, 'downloaded assets': 920, 'deleted assets': 0, 'total assets': 922}
```

Comment: Perfect, that gets exactly the information I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you might want to design an expression with two capturing groups, maybe similar to:

```
(?i)\b([a-z][a-z\s]+\bassets?)\s*:\s*(\d+)
```

and you can likely add more boundaries.

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r"(?i)\b([a-z][a-z\s]+\bassets?)\s*:\s*(\d+)"

test_str = """
report from:PCAT1.DB   created at:2019-06-27 14:32:24   generated at:2019-06-27 14:35:10

number of campaigns:466

unique assets:950   downloaded assets:920   deleted assets:0   total assets: 922

report from:PCAT1.DB   created at:2019-06-27 14:32:24   generated at:2019-06-27 14:35:10

number of campaigns:466

unique assets:950   downloaded assets:920   deleted assets:0   total assets: 922

"""

print(dict(re.findall(regex, test_str)))
```

#### Output

```
{'unique assets': '950', 'downloaded assets': '920', 'deleted assets': '0', 'total assets': '922'}
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/JhSDDZ/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/JhSDDZ/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I've booked marked those pages as I think they will be quite useful in the future.